# Can't dissolve certain edges

Tags: modeling

I can't tell why though...

I tried to select all the edges and dissolve them but to no avail.

I tried with only one edge selected but i wont do it...

Can someone help me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I made sure there were no doubles (W key). I tried Limited dissolves as well as Dissolve edges, buit made no changes...i use a mirror mod for this object and also applied it...this shouldnt bother mid but im planning to add a subsurf mod...so eventually i'll have to smooth with Loops and i might get confused...i've triple checked and i didnt find any ngons...its a quad face...

Comment: Could it be some active modifier? if you can, share the file on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then post here (add to the question text) the provided link

Comment: Sure i'll upload it in a second, ummm on the screenshot, im on the modifers tab with my  object in edit mode...

Comment: i've added it in the desc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ngons aren't the only problem which can prevent Dissolve from working, [non-manifold geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry/7914) is one more. There are internal faces in your mesh left after applying [Mirror modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html):

[image: screenshot-table]

Above *Select > Select All By Trait > Non-Manifold* was used to select all internal faces.

Remove the faces and then dissolve the edges with either *Limited Dissolve* or <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Edges*.

In more general case this is one of the problems which arise if you don't delete the faces which are on the mirror plane of the modifier (if you add Subsurf these will be visible as a seam in the middle of the mesh).

Comment: Thank you...that fixed it...i'll keep that in mind next time....

Comment: Btw is that the only way to fix that?

Comment: @AkashDigumber it's not the only one, you can delete mirrored part altogether and remirror it using modifier. Or you can delete the faces like above and with top planks selected run Limited Dissolve. The idea behind is that one can't dissolve edges if they are holding the face (inner one in your example) so it's more flexible to avoid those faces inside which are error geometry either way

Comment: Ohhhh ok....thank you very much once again...