# How to remove duplicate verts after spin tool?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, 3d-view, blend-files

I'm trying to reproduce tank wheels ("ITALIERI" (LEAST PERSPECTIVE)):

[image]

But there are too many vertexes and merging can lead to ngons.

[image]

**Edit:**

Second file:

[image]

**Edit #2:**

Made some progress with the topology; overlapping faces/edges as described here:

[image]

but there are still highlighted faces that seem separated from the mesh (on the tip of the spokes).

[Can't dissolve certain edges](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93213/cant-dissolve-certain-edges)

**Edit #3:**

If there are two or more overlapping faces with the same normals the resulting face appears "brighter".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your topology is a bit messy, to quickly fix it you can:

- Only keep one portion:

[image]

- Fix the topology, give it a *Mirror* modifier:

[image]

- Create an empty at the current origin of the object:

[image]

- Give your object an *Array* modifier, deactivate *Relative Offset*, activate *Object Offset* with the empty as *Object*, rotate the empty 37,72° (as you want 11 iterations), enable the *Merge* option then the *First and Last* option:

[image]

- Keep a copy of your object and empty. Apply the *Mirror* and the *Array* modifiers, then *Merge By Distance* to remove any overlapping vertices:

[image]

Edit:

Your topology is still bad, your faces are overlapping, etc:

[image]

Once you'll be good, you can extrude, use the *LoopTools* to make sure that you have nice circles, bevel the angle so that it will sharp when you'll have the *Subdivision Surface* modifier, etc...:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also you may need to keep only 1/11 of your object again and use the same *Array* modifier around an object, it allows you to work precisely on a portion of the object without having to repeat the operations all around.

Comment: Thanks! I still have overlapping edges and am unable to select the center edge loop (circle) to be extended. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Ok. I get something roughly similar but only when not applying the subsurf modif.

Comment: what do you mean? Maybe share a second file

Comment: Ok. Edited (reuploaded).

Comment: The inner vertexes do not form a face (cannot create a loop cut for the rest of the wheel; the mesh now looks like a crown :))

Comment: your topology is still not good, I've edited my answer

Comment: I still can't seem to get to pciture #5; how do you apply the array modifier so that you have no face overlap in the end result?

Comment: look at picture #2, you need to make sure that the shape is 1/11 of the whole ring and that you have quads with no overlapping vertices/edges/faces. You need to continue working on this part until it works fine, then you can apply the modifiers

Comment: I've made some progress but now the tips of the spokes are highlighted and behave differently when selected; one face is selected if any of the four faces making up the spoke is selected, but Alt + LMB behavior if any of the lower faces (beneath the spokes) is clicked.